# Calculating array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a measurand like 55.9 mm and I want to divide it in different gauge blocks. Just like:
55.9 mm = 1.4 mm + 1.5 mm + 50 mm + 3 mm

But it can happen that I don't have the 1.4 gauge block. So I need to use something like:

55.9 mm = 1.44 mm + 1.46 mm + 50 mm + 3 mm

As you see i have to substitute the 1.4 and 1.5 gauge blocks.

I am wrinting a PHP-script that calculates which possible gauge blocks I can use, based on the available gauge blocks.

How is it possible to check, wich gauge block with two decimal places replaces a gauge block with one decimal place.

The available blocks are stored in an array.

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php

function decimalPlaces($number) {
    $str = strval($number);
    $pos = strrpos($number, '.');
    return ($pos===false ? 0 : strlen($str)-$pos-1);
}

function gaugeBlocks($measurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3){
    if($measurement == 0){
    return;
}
$dp = decimalPlaces($measurement);
$gauge = array();

if($dp == 3){
    foreach($em3 as $em){
        $newMeasurement = round($measurement, 3) - $em;
        if(decimalPlaces($measurement - $em) == 2){
            echo "Neuer Messwert: ".$newMeasurement." nach Abzug des Endmasses: ".$em."<br />";
            $gauge[] = $em;
            if($newMeasurement == 0){
                echo "HELL NO 3";
            }else{
                gaugeBlocks($newMeasurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);
            }
        }
    }
}

if($dp == 2){
    $splitDec = explode(".", round($measurement, 2));
    $zielEM = floatval("1.".$splitDec[1]);

    if($zielEM < 1.50){
        foreach($em2 as $em){
            if($em == $zielEM){
                $newMeasurement = round($measurement, 2)-$em;
                echo "Neuer Messwert: ".$newMeasurement." nach Abzug des Endmasses: ".$em."<br />";
                if(decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 1 || decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 0){
                    $gauge[] = $em;
                    if($newMeasurement == 0){
                        echo "HELL NO 2";
                    }else{
                        gaugeBlocks($newMeasurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $lastDigitMeasurement = floatval(substr($measurement, -1));
                $lastDigitEM = floatval(substr($em, -1));
                if($lastDigitEM == $lastDigitMeasurement){
                    $newMeasurement = round($measurement, 2)-$em;
                    echo "Neuer Messwert: ".$newMeasurement." nach Abzug des Endmasses: ".$em."<br />";
                    if(decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 1 || decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 0){
                        $gauge[] = $em;
                        if($newMeasurement == 0){
                            echo "HELL NO 2";
                        }else{
                            gaugeBlocks($newMeasurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $nextEM = $zielEM-0.5;
        foreach($em2 as $em){
            if($em == $nextEM){
                echo "da noch?";
                $newMeasurement = round($measurement, 2)-$em;
                echo "Neuer Messwert: ".$newMeasurement." nach Abzug des Endmasses: ".$em."<br />";
                if(decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 1 || decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 0){
                    $gauge[] = $em;
                    if($newMeasurement == 0){
                        echo "HELL NO 2";
                    }else{
                        gaugeBlocks($newMeasurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

if($dp == 1){
    $splitDec = explode(".", round($measurement, 1));
    $zielEM = floatval("1.".$splitDec[1]);
    if($zielEM <= 1.5){
        foreach($em1 as $em){
            if($em == $zielEM){
                $newMeasurement = round($measurement, 1)-$em;
                echo "Neuer Messwert: ".$newMeasurement." nach Abzug des Endmasses: ".$em."<br />";
                if(decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 1 || decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 0){
                    $gauge[] = $em;
                    if($newMeasurement == 0){
                        echo "HELL NO 2";
                    }else{
                        gaugeBlocks($newMeasurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);
                    }
                }
            }else{

                $lastDigitMeasurement = floatval(substr($measurement, -1));
                $lastDigitEM = floatval(substr($em, -1));
                if($lastDigitEM == $lastDigitMeasurement){
                    $newMeasurement = round($measurement, 1)-$em;
                    echo "Neuer Messwert: ".$newMeasurement." nach Abzug des Endmasses: ".$em."<br />";
                    if(decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 1 || decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 0){
                        $gauge[] = $em;
                        if($newMeasurement == 0){
                            echo "HELL NO 2";
                        }else{
                            gaugeBlocks($newMeasurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $nextEM = $zielEM-0.5;
        foreach($em1 as $em){
            if($em == $nextEM){
                $newMeasurement = round($measurement, 1)-$em;
                echo "Neuer Messwert: ".$newMeasurement." nach Abzug des Endmasses: ".$em."<br />";
                if(decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 1 || decimalPlaces($newMeasurement) == 0){
                    $gauge[] = $em;
                    if($newMeasurement == 0){
                        echo "HELL NO 2";
                    }else{
                        gaugeBlocks($newMeasurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $lastDigitMeasurement = floatval("2.".substr($measurement, -1));
                //Solve problem here...


            }
        }

    }
}

if($dp == 0){
    foreach($em0 as $em){
        $em = round($em, 0);
        $newMeasurement = round($measurement, 0) - $em;
        if($newMeasurement >= 0){
            echo "Neuer Messwert: ".$newMeasurement." nach Abzug des Endmasses: ".$em."<br />";
            $gauge[] = $em;
            gaugeBlocks($newMeasurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);
        }
        if($newMeasurement == 0){
            exit;               
        }
    }
}

return; 
}

echo "<a href='menu.php'>Zurück</a><br />";
echo "<br />";
echo $_POST["mass"];
echo "<br />";



$tray = array();
if($_POST["halle"] == 1){
    $tray = ["W7", "W8"];
}
if($_POST["halle"] == 2){
    $tray = ["W4", "W10"];
}

$em3 = ["1.005"];
$em2 = array();
$em1 = array();
$em0 = array();

$wert = 1;
$em1 = [0.5];
$em0[] = $wert;
while($wert<1.5){
    $wert = $wert+0.01;
    if(decimalPlaces($wert) == 2){
        $em2[] = $wert;
    }else{
        $em1[] = $wert;
    }
}
$wert = 1.5;
while($wert<25){
    $wert = $wert+0.5;
    if(decimalPlaces($wert) != 0){
        $em1[] = $wert;
    }else{
        $em0[] = $wert;
    }
}
$wert = 25;
while($wert<100){
    $wert = $wert+25;
    $em0[] = $wert;
}

/*
 * Alle Möglichen Stückelungen mit vorhandenen Maßen
 */
$measurement = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $_POST['mass']));
$usedBlocks = array();
$em3 = array_reverse($em3);
foreach(array_keys($em3) as $em){
    $em3[$em] = round($em3[$em], 3);
}

$em2 = array_reverse($em2);
foreach(array_keys($em2) as $em){
    $em2[$em] = round($em2[$em], 2);
    if(($em2[$em] == 1.37)){
        unset($em2[$em]);
    }
}



$em1 = array_reverse($em1);
foreach(array_keys($em1) as $em){
    $em1[$em] = round($em1[$em], 1);
    if(($em1[$em] == 1.4)){
        unset($em1[$em]);
    }
}

$em0 = [100, 75, 50, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1];
foreach(array_keys($em0) as $em){
    $em0[$em] = round($em0[$em], 0);
}


$usedBlocks[] = gaugeBlocks($measurement, $em0, $em1, $em2, $em3);

?>
```

Comment: How are the available gauge blocks determined?

Comment: Show your current code, so we see a bit more what you are trying to do

Comment: Find the largest available gauge that's less than the measurement. Add it to the result list and subtract it from the measurement. Repeat this until you have no more available gauges blocks.

Comment: sound like an interview problem

Comment: Maybe my question is too complex:
If I have the number 2.9 and an array with different float-values like
`array {1.41, 1.42, 1.43, 1.44, 1.45, 1.46, 1.47, 1.48, 1.49, 1.5, ...}`
how can I check which combinations eqal 2.9, e. g.:
2.9 = 1.41 + 1.49 or 2.9 = 1.42 + 1.48 ...

Comment: @Joe `foreach` and `if statement`.

Comment: @Barmar that method won't always work. For instance, you need overall 9m, the gauge you have is 4m, 3m, 3m, 3m. The method will pick 4m first...

Comment: What you need is to compute all the possible combinations of existing gauges length. And select the one which is most close to and smaller than or equal to the desired length.

Comment: @PeterPeng -> how do I compute all the possible combinations? That is actually the question

Comment: Need a bit of Combinatorics . Depends on you array size, there will be 2^(arraySize) of possible outcomes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance an gaugeArray = [1, 4, 11.3, 48.6];

There are 4 elements in the array 2^(4) = 16 possible outcomes.

Combination denoted by binary bit:

(1) 0000
(2) 0001
(3) 0010
(4) 0011
(5) 0100
(6) 0101
(7) 0110
(8) 0111
(9) 1000
(10)1001
(11)1010
(12)1011
(13)1100
(14)1101
(15)1110
(16)1111

So, you can try:

```js
<?php

$gaugeString = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'gauges');
$desired = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'desired');

$gaugeArray = array();
$need2RunRoutine = false;
$desiredValue  = 12.6;
if(isset($gaugeString) && isset($desired))
{
 $gaugeStringSplits = explode(",", $gaugeString);
 for($i=0; $i<count($gaugeStringSplits); $i++)
 {
  array_push($gaugeArray, floatval($gaugeStringSplits[$i]));
 }
 $desiredValue  = floatval($desired);
 $need2RunRoutine = true;
}
else
{
 $gaugeArray = array(1, 4, 11.3, 48.6);
}
$gaugeInputString = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($gaugeArray); $i++)
{
 $gaugeInputString .= ($gaugeArray[$i].', ');
}
$gaugeInputString = trim($gaugeInputString, ',');
$gaugeInputString = trim($gaugeInputString, ', ');
echo '<form method="GET">Enter gauges(seperated by ,):<br><input type="text" name="gauges" value="'.$gaugeInputString.'"><br>Enter Desired Length:<br><input type="text" name="desired" value="'.$desiredValue.'"><br><input type="submit"></from>';
if($need2RunRoutine)
{
 $bitSelector = array();
 for($i=0; $i<count($gaugeArray); $i++)
 {
  array_push($bitSelector, (0x01<<$i) );
 }
  
 $possibleOutcomesCount = pow(2,count($gaugeArray));
 //echo '$possibleOutcomesCount: '.$possibleOutcomesCount;
 $possibleCombinations = array();  //will contain all possible outcomes

 for($i=0; $i<$possibleOutcomesCount; $i++)     //16  combinations
 {
    $combineValue = 0;
    for($j=0; $j<count($gaugeArray); $j++)
    {
      if( ($i & $bitSelector[$j]) == $bitSelector[$j])
      {
         $combineValue  += $gaugeArray[$j];
      }
    }
  //echo '<br>'.$combineValue.'<br>';
    array_push($possibleCombinations, $combineValue);
 }

 //after this you need to select the value which is most close to your desired value from $possibleCombinations
 $bestMatch = -1;
 $matchIndex = -1;
 for($i=0; $i<count($possibleCombinations); $i++)
 {
    if( ($bestMatch < $possibleCombinations[$i]) && ($possibleCombinations[$i] <= $desiredValue) )
     {
        $bestMatch = $possibleCombinations[$i];
   $matchIndex = $i;
     }
 }
 if($matchIndex >= 0)
 {
  echo '<br><br><br>Best Match value: '.$bestMatch.'<br>';
  $outputString = '';
  for($i=0; $i<count($bitSelector); $i++)
  {
   if(($matchIndex & $bitSelector[$i]) == $bitSelector[$i])
   {
    $outputString .= ($gaugeArray[$i].'+ ');
   }
  }
  $outputString = trim($outputString, '+ ');
  $outputString .= ' = '.$bestMatch.' which is most close to desired value '.$desiredValue;
  echo $outputString;
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'No gauge conbination can give that desired value.';
 }
 
}
?>
```

Now $possibleCombinations contains all possible value. You need to select the one which is most close and smaller or equals to the desired value.

Comment: Nice answer! I've never worked with this "bitSelector"-thing. But as soon as I understood what it does and how it works and when I were able to adopt it to my problem, I will mark your answer as accepted! 
Do you have further information about this bit-thing? Any links etc.?

Comment: Fixed some typo in the code, here is a more generic example